# Expression engine, Expresso Store Payment Module

Tags: php, expressionengine, expresso-store

I am using Expression engine for one of my ecommerce project and using Expresso store for ecommerce functionality. Expresso store using omnipay that have multiple payment gateways integrated in it.

I want to create a custom payment gateway for Expresso store as per expression engine stander.

Is there any example module available for this.

Comment: Hi 
You didn't mention expression engine version in your question

Comment: I am using expression engine 2.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can review my extension that i have build for Expression engine/Expresso store.
Here is the url
https://github.com/emerico/store_payex